# How to handle task level calendars in auto-scheduling in DHTMLX Gantt

Tags: dhtmlx

I am facing issue with auto-scheduling when i am using task level calendars with different working days and holidays along with link lag property to set lag and lead time between tasks. I am using forward planning with type 3 links between dependencies.
Then the start date of some tasks in not following the lag time passed in the links.
Note: I am not using time constraints still the task start and end dates are not correct after auto-scheduling.

But if I remove the task level calendars then the auto scheduling is working fine with lead and lag time between tasks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it is similar to a known bug in DHTMLX Gantt, but maybe it happens because of something else.
To be sure that it is a bug, please reproduce the issue in the following snippet, then click on the “Share” button and send me the link:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/3fae1b026

Or send me a ready demo with all the necessary files so that I can reproduce the issue locally.